# Can I apply fixed DC voltage to cluster of LiPO batteries to charge them?

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

I know the "proper" way to arrange LiPo batteries (18650's) is to isolate them as single cells.  But for now I'm retro-fitting a cluster of 6 batteries (2 groups in series, each group having 3 cells wired in parallel) that give a combined 8.4 volts (I guess).  This is to replace a 6-cell NiMH (1.2 v per cell, all wired in series) battery pack for a cordless sweeper (shark I think).  The LiPo batteries came bonded as 3 groups of 3 wired in series from an old laptop battery.

I'm going to take a 9V 1-amp wall wart and maybe add a diode to drop the voltage to 8 and simply wire that directly to the LiPo pack.  There will be no charge indicator, and charging sessions would be limited to 1 or 2 hours when the pack runs low.  The only thing I think I need to worry about is overcharging (over-voltage) but if the output is limited to 8 volts I don't see that as a problem.  Anyone see a problem with this?

Comment: Charging lithium batteries isn't something to do incorrectly.  There's a danger of cell imbalance, overheating, fire, explosion, etc.  Charge management for Li packs has to be done correctly to be safe.

Comment: These cells were wired in groups of 3 in parallel in the original battery pack, so there would have been no way to know if they were not balanced (at least at the group level).

Comment: "can you do this": yes. "is it safe to do this": no. "should you do this": absolutely not what are you thinking.

Comment: please explain failure mode.  The power supply is capable of only 1 amp.  Applied voltage will be at most 4 volts (per cell).  Even if left unattended for many hours, what happens to LiPo batteries when you apply, say, 4 volts to them?  Won't they just come up to 4 volts and then just sit there?  No current flow after that?

Comment: I have to find the duplicate but no, this will not work. Why? A 9V 1A power supply is not a charger. If you connect that power supply to an empty battery of say 6V, the supply can't get the voltage to go back to 9V, so it tries to output as much current as it can, hits the 1A limit and it most likely, instead of giving out 9V at 1A, shuts off due to overcurrent or undervoltage protections. You need a battery charger device, even if you use your 9V 1A power supply.

Comment: @PeggySchafer A real Li battery charger will have circuits to balance the cells, decrease or cut off charging if the cell temperature is out of a safe range, prevent charging if the cell voltage is too low (which can cause fires) and terminate charging at the proper voltage.  You might get away with your scheme, the only major danger I see is if the cells get way out of balance or they get old enough that the internal impedance causes excess temperature rise, but I wouldn't take the risk.  You could cause a fire or injury.